# Retrieve affine schemes by adjunction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, affine-schemes, adjoint-functors

In an introductory course about schemes, I've seen the adjunction 
$$ {\mathbf{LocRngSpace}}^{\mathrm{op}} \overset{\mathrm{Spec}}{\underset{\Gamma}{\leftrightarrows}} \mathbf{Ring}, $$
where $\mathbf{LocRngSpace}$ is the category of locally ringed spaces, $\mathbf{Ring}$ the category of commutative unitary rings, $\Gamma$ the global sections functor and $\mathrm{Spec}$ the usual functor taking a ring to the affine scheme on its spectrum.

I'm then trying to work out the following idea (as an exercise) : retrieving the notion of affine schemes by applying Freyd's adjoint theorem to the global sections functor 
$$  {\mathbf{LocRngSpace}}^{\mathrm{op}} \overset{\Gamma}{\to} \mathbf{Ring}.$$
I have already showed that $\mathbf{LocRngSpace}$ is cocomplete and that $\Gamma$ commutes with limits (of ${\mathbf{LocRngSpace}}^{\mathrm{op}}$).

It remains to prove that $\Gamma$ satisfies the set condition : that is for every ring $R$ there exists a set $I$ indexing a family $(X_i)$ of locally ringed spaces and a family of ring morphisms $(r_i \colon R \to \Gamma X_i)$ such that for every locally ringed space $X$ and $f \colon R \to \Gamma X$, there is $i \in I$ and a morphism of locally ringed spaces $h \colon X \to X_i$ such that commutes
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} 
R @>{f}>> \Gamma X \\
@V{r_i}VV @| \\
\Gamma X_i @>>{\Gamma h}> \Gamma X.
\end{CD}$$
Of course, I'm trying to avoid using $I = \{\ast\}$ and $X_\ast = \mathrm{Spec R}$… However, knowing about $\mathrm{Spec}$, I know that $\Gamma X$ could be any ring : so I can't expect some simplification about the $f$s. I've tried to take $I$ the set of prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ of $R$ and $X_{\mathfrak p} = (\{\ast\}, R_{\mathfrak p})$ but it will factorize only the $f \colon R \to B$ such that the ideal of $R$ generated by $R \setminus f^{-1}(B^\times)$ is strict. So it seems that I have to consider (for the $X_i$) locally ringed spaces that aren't (all) singleton as a topological space : but then I dangerously drift to $\mathrm{Spec} R$…

Any hint ?

Answer (score 9):

I have pondered about the same question a few months ago, but couldn't verify the solution set condition either. Note that since $\{\mathbb{Z}[T]\}$ is colimit-dense in $\mathsf{CRing}$, it suffices to consider $R=\mathbb{Z}[T]$. Therefore, it suffices to find a solution set for global sections, or equivalently to show that $\Gamma$ considered as a functor $\mathsf{LRS}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is a representable functor. But I don't know how to do that.

Let me mention two things about the adjunction, aimed at the category-theory-minded reader.

1. Assume that we already know that there is a functor $\mathrm{Spec}$ solving the desired adjunction $\hom(X,\mathrm{Spec}(R)) = \hom(R,\Gamma(X))$. Taking $X=(*,K)$ for a field $K$, it follows easily that the underlying set of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is the set of prime ideals of $R$, and that the residue field at a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is precisely $\mathrm{Quot}(R/\mathfrak{p})$. Taking $X=(*,A)$ for some local rings $A$, it follows more precisely that the stalk at $\mathfrak{p}$ is $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and that we have $\mathfrak{p} \prec \mathfrak{q}$ iff $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$. These are well-known properties of the spectrum constructed in the usual way, but as you can see this follows from the adjunction! Unfortunately I don't know how to derive the topology and the sheaf completely. In particular, I don't know how to derive from the adjunction that $\mathrm{Spec}$ is fully faithful, or equivalently if the counit $R \to \Gamma(\mathrm{Spec}(R))$ is an isomorphism. Remember that this requires some calculation with the explicit construction of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ - somehow I doubt that we can get rid of it.
2. Actually the global section functor factors as $\mathsf{LRS} \to \mathsf{RS} \to \mathsf{CRing}^{\mathrm{op}}$. Here, $\mathsf{RS}$ ($\mathsf{LRS}$) denotes the category of (locally) ringed spaces. In order to show that it has a right adjoint, it suffices to find right adjoints for a) the global section functor $\mathsf{RS} \to \mathsf{CRing}^{\mathrm{op}}$, and b) for the forgetful functor $\mathsf{LRS} \to \mathsf{RS}$. For a) we just take $R \mapsto (*,R)$. For b), one might still try to appeal to Freyd's Adjoint Functor Theorem, but actually it's much easier to construct the right adjoint directly: Given a ringed space $X$, we would like to "make" the stalks $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ local. The idea is to add prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ to our space $\tilde{X}$ and define the structure sheaf in such a way that $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X},(x,\mathfrak{p})} = (\mathcal{O}_{X,x})_{\mathfrak{p}}$, because this is a local ring. The details of this construction can be found in Gillam's paper [Localization of ringed spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2139). But I would like to point out that in some sense *this* construction is very evident, you could have come up with it yourself. In my opinion, the generalization from commutative rings to arbitrary ringed spaces does *not* make the adjunction more complicated, but rather it decomposes the adjunction into its essential parts, each one being easy to achieve.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't answer your question - this is only a long comment ...

Comment: And it is very much appreciated. Thanks. The article you linked seems very interesting !